# Create ctypes binding to C function with variable length arg list

Tags: python, c, ctypes

Assuming I have C function with variable length argument list:

```
int some_func(int arg1 , ... );
```

Is it possible (easy?) to call this function from python using ctypes?

**Update:**

Implemented suggestion from cedric and that worked like charm:

```
libc = ctypes.CDLL( "/lib64/libc.so.6" , ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL )
printf = getattr( libc , "printf")
printf("String1:%s int:%d String2:%s double:%lg\n" , "Hello" , 10 , "World" , ctypes.c_double( 3.1415 ))
```

With the ctypes.c_double( ) function as the only minor nuisance. So - all in all this was easier than I though; however I guess the possiblity to fxxx up with va_args remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can bind the [libc printf function](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions-continued), that is a really good example of va_args using, I think you'll be able to create a binding with any function.